# How to check if a specific user reacted with a specific emoji?

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

I was trying to make it so that a user can only react once on a message.

This is my attempt

```js
if(reaction.users.cache.has(user.id)) {
  reaction.remove().catch(err => {return;})
}
```

This always removes the reaction (I understand it's because the user just reacted). I tried checking the reaction emojis like this:

```js
reaction.message.reactions.cache.some(r => r.emoji.name === 'my_emoji')
```

This always returns true because my bot reacts to it, and other people can also react.

I tried checking the docs but there is nothing like `MessageReaction.user` that could help.

How can I check if the specific user reacted with a specific emoji?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try accessing [ReactionUserManager](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/ReactionUserManager) along with [ReactionEmoji](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/ReactionEmoji) and check if the manager has the id *and* the current reaction's emoji is your target emoji.

```js
reaction.message.reactions.cache
   .filter(r => r.emoji.name === 'my_emoji')
   .some(r => r.users.cache.has(user.id));
```

Comment: I had 1 problem which I fixed myself, it was that when I was removing the reaction, I removed all reactions, but I solved it by changing it from `reaction.remove` to `reaction.users.remove(user)`